# Go. Writing []byte to file results in zero byte file

Tags: file, go, io, gob

I try to serialize a structured data to file. I looked through some examples and made such construction:

```
func (order Order) Serialize(folder string) {
    b := bytes.Buffer{}
    e := gob.NewEncoder(&b)
    err := e.Encode(order)
    if err != nil { panic(err) }

    os.MkdirAll(folder, 0777)
    file, err := os.Create(folder + order.Id)
    if err != nil {  panic(err) }
    defer file.Close()


    writer := bufio.NewWriter(file)
    n, err := writer.Write(b.Bytes())

    fmt.Println(n)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

`Serialize` is a method serializing its object to file called by it's *id* property. I looked through debugger - byte buffer contains data before writing. I mean object is fully initialized. Even `n` variable representing quantity of written bytes is more than a thousand - the file shouldn't be empty at all. The file is created but it is totally empty. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`bufio.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Writer) (as the package name hints) uses a buffer to cache writes. If you ever use it, you must call [`Writer.Flush()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Writer.Flush) when you're done writing to it to ensure the buffered data gets written to the underlying [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer).

Also note that you can directly write to an [`os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File), no need to create a buffered writer "around" it. (`*os.File` implements `io.Writer`).

Also note that you can create the [`gob.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#Encoder) directly directed to the `os.File`, so even the [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) is unnecessary.

Also [`os.MkdirAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#MkdirAll) may fail, check its return value.

Also it's better to "concatenate" parts of a file path using [`filepath.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Join) which takes care of extra / missing slashes at the end of folder names.

And last, it would be better to signal the failure of `Serialize()`, e.g. with an `error` return value, so the caller party has the chance to examine if the operation succeeded, and act accordingly.

So `Order.Serialize()` should look like this:

```
func (order Order) Serialize(folder string) error {
    if err := os.MkdirAll(folder, 0777); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    file, err := os.Create(filepath.Join(folder, order.Id))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    if err := gob.NewEncoder(file).Encode(order); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time: I'm totally new to Go and it's 'infrastructure'. Thank you very much for detailed explanation, your answer is rather perfect.